# Как поменять значение селекта кликая на кнопку с помощью jquery?

Tags: jquery

так пробовал через консоль не получается
$('select')[0][1].trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

```js
const select = $("select");

select
  .find(".q1, .q3")
  .attr("selected", "selected")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="3" multiple>
  <option class="q1">пункт 1</option>
  <option class="q2">пункт 2</option>
  <option class="q3">пункт 3</option>
  <option class="q4">пункт 4</option>
  <option class="q5">пункт 5</option>
</select>
```

полезный материал

[IDE в браузере](https://codesandbox.io/), можно эксперементировать и делиться кодом

[api.jquery](https://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

`$('select')[0][1]` —— `$('select')` собирает все элементы `<select>` на странице, `[0]` достает первый элемент из коллекции, который уже не jQuery-объект (а значит дальше у него не будет никаких jQuery-методов, в том числе и `.trigger()`). Но у первого select нет свойства `[1]` — с этого места оно == undefined.

Там и не нужен клик, можно прямо выставить значение селекта:

```js
$('select').eq(0).prop("selectedIndex", 2);

// $('select')[0].selectedIndex = 2;

// document.querySelectorAll('select')[0].selectedIndex = 2; // без jQuery
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>- -</option>
  <option>1111</option>
  <option>2222</option>
  <option>3333</option>
</select>
```

Если клик параллельно должен делать еще какое-то действие, кликнуть можно так:

```js
$('select').eq(0).find('option').eq(2).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>- -</option>
  <option>1111</option>
  <option onclick="console.log('clicked!')">2222</option>
  <option>3333</option>
</select>
```